# Spring Kafka - Centralized @KafkaListener logging

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I'd like to centralize all the @KafkaTemplate message logging, when a message arrives, when the processing success, and when an exception is thrown by a @KafkaListener

I don't want to use AOP, due to the performance impact, i would prefer to use a **RecordInterceptor** like this: [Log the exceptions thrown in spring kafka listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69569935/log-the-exceptions-thrown-in-spring-kafka-listener)

I'm using the **KafkaAutoConfiguration** (all configured via properties), so the auto configuration is creating a ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory bean without a RecordInterceptor configured

I thought that having a RecordInterceptor bean in the spring context would be enough, but it's not the case, it doesn't intercept anything (the @KafkaListener keep receiveing messages correctly)

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
public class LoggingRecordInterceptor implements RecordInterceptor<String, Object> {

    @Override
    public ConsumerRecord<String, Object> intercept(ConsumerRecord record) {
        log.info("sample logging");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ConsumerRecord<String, Object> intercept(ConsumerRecord record, Consumer consumer) {
        log.info("sample logging");
        return RecordInterceptor.super.intercept(record, consumer);
    }

    @Override
    public void success(ConsumerRecord record, Consumer consumer) {
        log.info("sample logging");
        RecordInterceptor.super.success(record, consumer);
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(ConsumerRecord record, Exception exception, Consumer consumer) {
        log.info("sample logging");
        RecordInterceptor.super.failure(record, exception, consumer);
    }
}
```

What am i missing? **How can i configure it using KafkaAutoConfiguration**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your assumption is correct. The `KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration` accepts a `ObjectProvider<RecordInterceptor<Object, Object>>` ans its auto-wired property. Then that one is set into a `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer`. It is there since Spring Boot `2.2.0`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/eeda12bd58c2b49e6a053fc545eade7168c0ff1f

Comment: What version of Boot are you using? Boot auto configuration of a (unique) `RecordInterceptor` was added in 2.2/2.3 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/17322 - use a debugger in the `KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration` constructor to see why it is not working - if you can't figure it out, post an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) someplace.

Comment: I'm using spring boot 2.5.12. In the KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration constructor, i evaluated recordInterceptor #getIfUnique and #getIfAvailable and #getObject, all of them returns null. It's not a bean creation order issue, it seems the LoggingRecordInterceptor is created before the KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration

Comment: That's correct: end-user beans really must be created before an auto-configuration to give it a chance to back-off because we have just overridden something for our own reason. May be the `RecordInterceptor` is from different package? As Gary said: simple project from you to let us reproduce would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I think it's a Spring bug.

**KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration** constructor has the following signature:

```java
KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration(...,
            ObjectProvider<RecordInterceptor<Object, Object>> recordInterceptor) {}
```

My `LoggingRecordInterceptor` was implementing `RecordInterceptor<String, Object>`

I thought it was supposed to work (since String obviously extends Object), but actually spring was not able to inject it correctly.

So i changed my `LoggingRecordInterceptor` as the following, and now works fine.

But i think it's a spring bug, it should handle generics, since the RecordInterceptor interface suggests it.

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
public class LoggingRecordInterceptor implements RecordInterceptor<Object, Object> {

    @Override
    public ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> intercept(@NonNull ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> consumerRecord) {
        log.info("Topic: {} - Message received - Payload: {}",
                consumerRecord.topic(), consumerRecord.value());
        return consumerRecord;
    }

    @Override
    public void success(@NonNull ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> consumerRecord,
                        @NonNull Consumer<Object, Object> consumer) {
        log.info("Topic: {} - Message processed - Payload: {}",
                consumerRecord.topic(), consumerRecord.value());
        RecordInterceptor.super.success(consumerRecord, consumer);
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(@NonNull ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> consumerRecord,
                        @NonNull Exception exception,
                        @NonNull Consumer<Object, Object> consumer) {
        log.error("Topic: {} - Error processing a message - Payload: {}",
                consumerRecord.topic(), consumerRecord.value());
        RecordInterceptor.super.failure(consumerRecord, exception, consumer);
    }
}
```